# How to categorize those singularity point?

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series, singularity

Given $$
f(z)=\frac{z^{n}+1}{z}-z e^{\frac{1}{z}}
$$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $z \in \mathbb{C}$

I am asked to find all the singulairiez points of $f(z)$

So from what I see, for every $n$  the only point is $z=0$ and since it is neither pole or removable singularity of $e^{\frac{1}{z}}$ it is neither pole or removable singularity of $f$

Is this argue true? or did I miss something here?

Comment: Looks good to me.  It's called an essential singularity.